# How to enable SUMO TraCI using SimuLTE and Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using [SimuLTE](http://simulte.com/add_veins.html) and Veins simulating sending safety message via LTE. The content of the message depends on the real-time values of the traffic, e.g., mean speed. In order to get such values, I plan to use `TraCICommandInterface` supported by Veins. However, I could not find out how and where I can do this. To be specific, in Veins without SimuLTE, I know the vehicle node is a module of `TraCIMobility`, which has an application layer, where we can customize the functions for receiving/sending messages, such as wsm, and managed by `TraCIScenarioManager`. However in the [simulation example provided by SimuLTE](https://github.com/inet-framework/simulte/blob/master/simulations/cars/omnetpp.ini), the vehicle/node is a module of `VeinInetMobility`, which is managed by `VeinInetManager`. Neither of them are using `TraCICommandInterface` or `TraCIMobility`. Besides, the [lte applications](https://github.com/inet-framework/simulte/tree/master/src/apps) are not using the same layer as [BaseWaveApplLayer](https://github.com/JiaGuoWMU/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc), where we can take some action as soon as the vehicle/node updates the position. Can anyone help explain how I could possibly implement the following using SimuLTE and Veins:

1. In order to monitor the vehicle/node values using TraCI, which class should I modify to use TraCI? VeinsInetMobility, VeinsInetManager or else?
2. How can I take action in the application only when there is a position update to the vehicle/node?
3. What is the essential difference between VeinsInetMobility and TraCIMobility? Can I use the latter for LTE scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Veins 4.6, a `TraCIMobility` module is used to update the **Veins** channel models every time a node's position changes. Quite similarly, in Veins_INET of Veins 4.6, a `VeinsInetMobility` module is used to update the **INET Framework** channel models every time a node's position changes. Because SimuLTE uses INET Framework channel models, this is the class that must be used here (otherwise the INET channel models would not know, e.g, whether two nodes are too far away to communicate).

If you want to take action every time a SUMO time step has completed, you can just add this to the [`executeOneTimestep` method of TraCIScenarioManager](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L561).

Note that if you ever want to interact with the SUMO vehicle via the `VeinsInetMobility` module (e.g., changing a vehicle's route) a few changes will be necessary: Veins_INET of Veins 4.6 does not track a node's external id (the ID that SUMO uses to refer to the corresponding vehicle), so this would need to be added to [`VeinsInetMobility` (line 54)](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.cc#L54) along with code to use it, similar to [`TraCIMobility` (line 127)](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h#L127).

Comment: Is [executeOneTimestep method of TraCIScenarioManager](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L561) also involved in `VeinsInetMobility`?

Comment: If so, is that because `VeinsInetManager` inherits `TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd`, which further inherits `TraCIScenarioManager`?

Comment: Another question is once I need to take some action, e.g., `slowDown`, I need to send this alert to both the server and nearby vehicles (via D2D). In which class am I supposed to do so?

Comment: Is that possible for a node to be both `VeinsInetMobility` and `TraCIMobility`?

Comment: this sounds like a different question to the one you initially posed. In the interest of keeping questions and answers relevant to one another, may I ask you to open a new question for this?

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks for the reminder. I am opening a new question for this now.

Comment: A question regarding the [executeOneTimestep method of TraCIScenarioManager](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L561): can I put the action function in [updateModulePosition](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L461) instead, if I only want to control the vehicles with the application (e.g., penertration=0.5)?